# how to order by date and by group mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, mssql-jdbc

I would like to know how to regroup the results from mysql queries according to date by grouping.

Table Name = Visit_History

[image: PIC FOR REFERENCE]

Comment: include your query.

Comment: Good grief. Surely there are some questions that should never be asked.

Answer (score 0):

order first by group, and then by date

```
SELECT * FROM Visit_History ORDER BY Ref_Num, Ref_Date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ORDER BY` for this ,

```
SELECT * FROM Visit_History ORDER BY Ref_Num, Ref_Date
```